# Finding three elements in an array that are not adjacent

Tags: java

This the question I must answer-

> Given an array of ints, return true if the value 3 appears in the array exactly 3 times, and no 3's are next to each other.
>
> ```
> haveThree({3, 1, 3, 1, 3}) → true
> haveThree({3, 1, 3, 3}) → false
> haveThree({3, 4, 3, 3, 4}) → false
> ```

This is my solution:

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++) {
      if (nums[i] == 3 && nums[i+1] ==3) {
          return false;
      } 
      else
         if ((nums[i]==3 && nums[i+1]!=3)||(nums[i]==3 && nums[i+1]!=3)) {
            count ++;
         }
  }
  return count ==3;
}
```

It fails for some tests. For example `{3,1,3,1,3}` should result in true being returned; however, false is returned and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Did you debug the program to see what value you get for `count`?

Comment: no- I am using the coding bat ide

Comment: What's the point of that `if` condition?

Comment: Why do you need the else-if statement?  Just compare nums[i] and nums[i+1], if they both aren't 3, increment count and loop again.

Comment: if theres is 2 threes beside each other then it automatically fails.

Comment: one must be a three @TastyMallows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails for that example because you don't check the last index, presumably to fix the out of bounds error for checking if two 3's are next to eachother.  Also the or condition in your second if statement is redundant.

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 3 && nums[i+1] ==3) {
            return false;
        } 
        if ((nums[i]==3)) { //removed redundant condition and doesn't need to be an else
            count ++;
        }
    }
    // check the last index, you've already ensured the second to last is not also a 3
    if(nums[nums.length-1] == 3) {
        count++;
    }
    return count == 3;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see about the last index, that makes sense thanks.

Comment: @JerryMurphy Sure thing! Take note that I changed the `if` statements, you didn't need as many conditions as you had, and there was no point to using `else if`.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer that helped me more to understand where I was going wrong, hope @Keppil not too upset when his answer was more elegant!

Comment: @JerryMurphy: Of course not. :) You should always select the answer that you feel helped you the most.

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop all the way to `nums.length` to count all occurences. Also, there is no need for the `else` statement. I would do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == 3) {
        if ((i < nums.length - 1) && (nums[i + 1] == 3)) {
            return false;
        }
        count++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: THanks keppil your solution is more concise but took me a few minutes to figure out,still a noob., Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not comparing the final value, you can't tell if the last array element is a three or not. What I would do (to guarantee going through each element as needed) is add a flag boolean that lets you know if the previous value was a three or not (resetting it back to false if the current value is not three).

My example:

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
   int count = 0;
   boolean flag = false;

   for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if(nums[i] == 3) { // The current value is a 3

         if(flag) { // Previous value was a 3, rejecting.
            return false; 
         }
         else { // We have another 3, set the flag
            count++;
            flag = true; 
         }
      }
      else { // Since this wasn't a 3, we can set the flag back to false
         flag = false;
      }
   }
   return count == 3;
}
```

Comment: This flag business makes my brain hurt, gonna spend a bit of time figuring it out. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Actually now I understand it, never would have thought to tackle it like that. Cheers.

Comment: No problem! And yeah, it's just a different way of approaching the problem; instead of looking ahead to the next value, it somewhat remembers the last value that we looked at.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` statement also has [another form](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) designed for iteration through Collections and arrays, and can be used to make your loops more compact and easy to read.

```
boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0, prevNum = 0;
    for (int i : nums){
        if (i==3) {
            count++;
            if (prevNum == i)
                return false;
        }
        prevNum = i;
    }
    return count == 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As some people have already pointed out, you are not counting all the 3s that are present in the array. Your loop ends just before the last element in order to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

It is a logical error. Your code fails for the test case that you've mentioned because first `if` condition returns `false` when `i = 0`. I wrote the following code snippet when I practiced. Hope it helps.

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
  int threeCount = 0;
  boolean successive3s = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == 3) { 
      threeCount++;
    }
    if (nums[i] == 3 && (i + 1) < nums.length && nums[i + 1] == 3) 
      successive3s = true;      
  }

  return (!successive3s && threeCount == 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
   int count = 0;

   if(nums.length >= 1 && nums[0] == 3)
        count++;

    for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i - 1] == 3 && nums[i] == 3)
            return false;

        if(nums[i] == 3)
            count++;
    }

    return count == 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a trailing counter for mine.

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) 
{
  //We check to see if it is possible to get 3 without being in a row.
  //In this case, it is the smallest at five chars
  //E.G 31313, so if we have any size less than this, we know it to be false.
  if (nums.length >= 5)
  {
    //Create a counter to track how many 3's we have in a row, 
    //as well as how many we have total.
    int counterInRow = 0;
    int counterThrees = 0;
    //Check for 3's
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
      //If a number is 3, we increment both;
      if (nums[i] == 3)
      {
        counterInRow++;
        counterThrees++;
      }
      //Otherwise, we reset the amount in a row to 0;
      else
      {
        counterInRow = 0;
      }
      //If we have 2 or more in a row, we return false.
      if (counterInRow >= 2)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    //Return if the amount of the counterThrees equals 3 or not.
    return (counterThrees == 3);
  }
  //If we have less than 5 characters, it isn't possible. We then,
  //Return false;
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```